# How to establish "Wi-Fi Direct" connection with networked devices

Tags: android, networking, wifi, wifi-direct

Using "Wi-Fi direct" in Android 4.0+, is it possible to establish a connection pragmatically with a NON "Wi-Fi direct" enabled network device?

For example, is it possible to communicate with older smartphone (having Android 2.2 OS) with the latest 4.1 based Android Smartphone. I want to use Wi-Fi direct capabilities to perform FTP operation on various kinds of smartphones (android, iOS).

Answer (score 0):

I am using an APP named FileDrop which I think has the similar feature set you are looking for.

This is how it works:
4.1 based phone becomes GO and generates a Wi-Fi password to allow older phone to connect to it using legacy Wi-Fi just like connecting to a Wi-Fi access point. You can also use QR scanning instead of manual key-in of the password.